# Nginx Problem with Django-ckeditor package

Tags: python, django, nginx, ckeditor

I have deployed django application on ubuntu 20 and it gives me an error when trying to make messages

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ckeditor'
```

Everything is set up. On my local machine there is no such problem.

Comment: The last line of the group above is telling you what is missing. So check your Python installation library on the system that is feeding the web pages.

Comment: everything is installed @OldBoy

Comment: The message clearly states that the `ckeditor` module cannot be found. So either it is not installed, or has somehwo been installed in the wrong place. So you need to check the actual libraries to see where it is.

Answer (score 0):

first of all that's not the problem with `nginx`.

secondly, try installing ckeditor with `pip install django-ckeditor`

prefer making a req.txt from local.
If the problem is still there it could be due to virtual env. try using which django if the path is of your venv then its ok but if not your venv is corrupted so make a new one.